# Sqlite sum incorrect result

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sum

I tried calculate some result by sqlite. My query is `SELECT SUM(value) FROM Transaction`. I noticed strange behaviour. When result < 6 characters is ok, when result > 6 characters sqlite round result. For example if result 12345678 then sqlite return 1.23456e+07. Can anyone explain?

I use ormlite for work with sqlite on android. The value is BIG_DECIMAL. Ormlite store it like VARCHAR.

Comment: Which data type have the value column? It looks like an overflow..

Comment: That's just scientific notation - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation . Probably just depends on how you're printing/formatting the value. Post some code.

Comment: @Oscar I correct question

Comment: @laalto I did not print result. I saw result when debug.

Comment: Just curious... did you really name your table **Transaction**?

Comment: @DerGolem No, it is for example

Answer (score 2):

It's not an incorrect result but just the result formatted in [scientific E notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

Assuming the value is a `double` in your code, the behavior is [documented in `Double.toString(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29).

Comment: But 12345678 != 1.23456e+07 , 1.23456e+07 = 12345600. Correct formatting is 1.2345678e+07

Comment: If you want to print with more precision, format the value yourself.

Comment: I don't print value. I get this result from db after execute query "SELECT SUM(value) FROM Transaction"